# Linq query between dates

Tags: c#, linq, date

```
if ((!(searchStartDate == default(DateTime))) && (!(searchEndDate == default(DateTime))))
{
    requests = requests.Where(x => x.CreatedDate >= searchStartDate && x.CreatedDate <= searchEndDate);
}
```

When I try to search with `searchEndDate` the date isn't included

Eg.) When the start date is 14/4/15 and end date is 14/4/15 no results are returned but when  the start date is 14/4/15 and end date is 15/4/15 results are returned for the 14/4/15

Comment: Do keep in mind that a date like `2015-04-14` is actually `2015-04-14T00:00:00`. So if the start date and the end date are the same time you are asking for all records that are exactly midnight, and not for the full span of the day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I strongly suspect the problem is that your start and end date values are the exact same point in time - so only values *at* that exact point in time will be found.

For example, suppose you have:

```
searchStartDate: 2015-04-15T00:00:00
searchEndDate: 2015-04-15T00:00:00
Sample CreatedDate: 2015-04-15T12:34:56
```

Then the `CreatedDate` *doesn't* fall between `searchStartDate` and `searchEndDate`. You're really thinking of it as:

```
// Look ma, no time of day!
searchStartDate: 2015-04-15
searchEndDate: 2015-04-15
```

but because `DateTime` is a [broken model](http://blog.nodatime.org/2011/08/what-wrong-with-datetime-anyway.html), you can't indicate that with the type system. Instead, you basically need to do it by hand:

```
if (searchStartDate != default(DateTime) && searchEndDate != default(DateTime))
{
    // Include the *whole* of the day indicated by searchStartDate
    DateTime inclusiveStart = searchStartDate.Date;
    // Include the *whole* of the day indicated by searchEndDate
    DateTime exclusiveEnd = searchEndDate.Date.AddDays(1);
    requests = requests.Where(x => x.CreatedDate >= inclusiveStart
                                && x.CreatedDate < exclusiveEnd);
}
```

You could put use `.Date` in the query as well, but that may well be less efficient, as it effectively involves a calculation on each stored value - whereas my approach instead performs a calculation on the bounds instead, just once.

Answer (score 3):

If you are only interested in the dates then you should search *purely* on them, at the moment your search will also be including the time

```
x.CreatedDate.Date >= searchStartDate.Date && x.CreatedDate.Date <= searchEndDate.Date
```

Here's an example of why your current check fails - presuming you haven't set a specific time on your `searchStartDate`/`searchEndDate` then it will default to `12:00:00`, so your start & end date are actually `14/4/15 12:00:00`. With that being the case, unless you have a created date that *exactly* matches `14/4/15 12:00:00` then your query will yield no results. This is why when you set your end date to `15/4/15 12:00:00` you pull in the records that were created on `14/4/15`.

**UTC vs Local**

Also, you don't appear to mention how your dates are stored and how you are querying them? If you are storing dates in UTC then it's advisable you convert them back to local time for more accurate results. For example, I live in the UK and at the moment we are in [BST](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/bst) (UTC+1), assuming (hoping) you are storing records in UTC, a created at `06/06/2015 00:30:00` would actually be stored as `05/06/2015 23:30:00` once converted to UTC. Therefore, unless you converted this date back to local time before searching this record wouldn't be included in your query for `06/06/2015`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
if ((!(searchStartDate == default(DateTime))) && (!(searchEndDate == default(DateTime))))
{
    requests = requests.Where(x => x.CreatedDate >= searchStartDate && x.CreatedDate < searchEndDate.AddDays(1));
}
```

This is because `x.CreatedDate` is probably `14/4/15 10:00:00.000` that is greater than `14/4/15 00:00:00.000`.

Comment: It's a bit dirty though. I'm just wondering why it doesn't work.

Comment: @LukeOsborne it doesn't work because `x.CreatedDate` is probably `14/4/15 10:00:00.000` that is greater than `14/4/15 00:00:00.000`.