# retrieve data from a given period of time

Tags: c#

I am trying to get a list of items that were created in the past two weeks. I am able to retrieve 14 items but I want Items from 14 days. My code looks like this below. I am new to this language and I thought I fixed it but still has a problem. Any help would be apperciated

```
public ActionResult SolaceHistory()
    {

        var model = new SolaceHistoryList();
        model.Statuses = OnlineGivingContext.log_SolaceStatus.OrderByDescending(s => s.DateCreated).Take(14).ToList();
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: Hint: filtering is performed using `Where`. Consider what you're really trying to filter by. Bigger hint: consider how you'd construct a "cutoff" date so you can find things where `s.DateCreated >= cutoffDate`...

Comment: `.Where(x => x.DateCreated >= start)` where `start` is presumably `DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-14)` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linq query between dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30662009/linq-query-between-dates)

Comment: Thank you very much for all the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

use below function

```
public ActionResult SolaceHistory()
    {
var Criteria=DateTime.Now.AddDays(-14);
        var model = new SolaceHistoryList();
        model.Statuses = OnlineGivingContext.log_SolaceStatus.OrderByDescending(s => s.DateCreated.Date >= Criteria.Date).ToList();
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: I tried using that earlier but it gives me aSystem.NotSupportedException 
  Message=The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.
  Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
  StackTrace:
<Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>

Comment: Are you using syetem.linq namespace?

Answer (score 0):

```
     {
        var Criteria = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-14);
        var model = new SolaceHistoryList();
        model.Statuses = OnlineGivingContext.log_SolaceStatus
            .Where(st => st.DateCreated >= Criteria).
            OrderByDescending(s => s.DateCreated).ToList();
        return View(model);
    }
```

was able to solve my issue